# Redirecting grails application after spring session-timeout with web.xml

Tags: java, spring, session, grails

We are using the web.xml version of session-timeout, and are stumped on having it redirect to either the login page, or the logout page forcing the user to re-authenticate.

Currently we have this defined in our web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Which used in conjunction with our spring security core jars, works fine for invalidating the session after the timeout, but there is no redirecting of the screens, you can still browse through the application with no session.

How do we tell Spring to redirect at the end of that timeout?

URL mapping for intercepting the user

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="casProcessingFilterEntryPoint" pattern="/*">
    <security:custom-filter ref="casProcessingFilter" after="CAS_FILTER"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="http://login..edu/logout" invalidate-session="true"/> 
</security:http>
```

Comment: Can you post your URL/Security mappings? It almost sounds like you aren't securing your application to require authentication.

Comment: Updated with what we have so far.